# Using jQuery to reduce opacity of other elements with a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opacity

I have a block of images with captions and am using slideToggle to show and hide the captions:

```
    $('.imageholder').hover(function() {
    var $desc = $(this).next();
    $('.description').not($desc).slideUp('fast');
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
  });
```

Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euphemus/bdfv9vg8/3/)

When an image is clicked, the caption will reveal but I want to simultaneously reduce the opacity of the other images in the containing div (something like [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/about/the-team)). Would appreciate some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the hover function you can add a function to get your opacity back to 1 when your are not hovering your element. (Here: https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

You can try this:

```js
 $('.imageholder').hover(function() {
   var $desc = $(this).next();
   $('.description').not($desc).slideUp('fast');
   $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
   $(this).siblings('.imageholder').css({opacity: 0.2});
 },function(){
   $(this).siblings().css({opacity: 1});
 });
```

```css
.description {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageswrapper">
</div>
<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Placeholder">
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Placeholder">
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
<div class="imageholder">
  <img class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="Placeholder">
</div>
<div class="description">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding `$(this).siblings().css({opacity: 0.5})` but I don't think you are looking for opacity here, it's more of a filter to black and white rather than the alpha.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the current element from a jQuery selector like so:

```
$('.imageholder').not(this)
```

Here's a fiddle showing the images fading out (you'll have to fade them back up when you mouse out): https://jsfiddle.net/euphemus/bdfv9vg8/3/

Comment: Thanks. I think you just re-posted my Fiddle there. Could you try again?